# Update document on pusher event

Tags: javascript, pusher

Im new to JavaScript and pusher. I am making website with clickable grid, that I want to send pusher events every time one cell gets clicked, so the same cell would be marked for all other users. I managed to subscribe to pusher channel and receive incoming messages (Im sending them with some other script for now), but I keep failing at updating grid after receiving message.

```
var pusher = new Pusher('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', {
    cluster: 'eu',
    encrypted: true
});
var channel = pusher.subscribe('app');
var grid = clickableGrid({{y}},{{x}},function(el,row,col,i){
    el.className = 'clicked';
});

channel.bind('cell_marked', function(data) {
    var x = data['message'][0];
    var y = data['message'][1];
    grid.rows[x].cells[y].className == 'marked';
});

document.body.appendChild(grid);

function clickableGrid(rows, cols, callback){
    var i = 0;
    var grid = document.createElement('table');
    grid.className = 'grid';
    for (var r=0;r<rows;++r){
        var tr = grid.appendChild(document.createElement('tr'));
        for (var c=0;c<cols;++c){
            var cell = tr.appendChild(document.createElement('td'));
            cell.innerHTML = ++i;
            cell.addEventListener('click',(function(el,r,c,i){
                return function(){
                    callback(el,r,c,i);
                }
            })(cell,r,c,i),false);
        }
    }
    return grid;
}
```

Since I don't really know JS much I don't get why event listener for clicking cells works, while updating after receiving pusher notification doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `=` instead of `==` for assignment here:

```
grid.rows[x].cells[y].className == 'marked';
```

Comment: Wow, I am really blind. Thanks man, that did it. I guess I just needed someone else to take a look at it to see the obvious problem. Cheers!